# Tenses in a complex sentence

Tags: grammar

A wrote:
"I have a web page that is stylized with CSS".

B wrote:
"I have a web page that is stylised with CSS".
(Chrome's spell-checker is already complaining about "stylised)

C wrote:
"I have a web page that is styled by CSS".

Which is correct/is there a "correcter" (I know: "better") sentence?

Background:
A web page is something that a browser shows.
CSS is part of the logic that sets/changes the default style of all/portions of the web page.
(basics, and as best as I can explain...)

PS suggest edit to title...

Comment: I don't think ***styled*** or ***stylized*** (UK spelling ***stylised***) are suitable verbs for this context. Consider alternatives such as ***formatted using*** or ***created with***. There is the usage ***styled after [X]***, but that specifically means ***giving the appearance** [of being an actual X],* so it your context it would have to imply using some system that was just ***like*** CSS (but not the real thing, so it might not work properly with all software).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, Thank you.
"formatted" sound good, however, CSS stands for Cascading **Style** Sheets.

Comment: Styled is fine but stylized is definitely wrong. [Style as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/style) means "to give a particular style to". [Stylized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stylize) means done according to an unnatural, often traditional or conventionalized style, and is mostly used in art history and criticism.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in tense, all three sentences use the present tense in both the main clause "I have" and the relative clause "that is ..."

There is a choice of verb "stylize/stylise"  (these are just spelling variants, the first is more common in the US, the second in the UK, though "-ize" would be not be incorrect in the UK either)  or "style".

Dictionaries say that "stylize" can mean "to give something a distinctive appearance" and "style" can mean "to arrange something so it appears attractive". Web searches find examples of both "stylize with CSS" and "style with CSS"

Conclusion: you can use any of those three forms.

Personally I prefer "style with CSS",  websearches suggest that this is used in more formal contexts (books, guides to webpage design), whereas "stylize" tends to get used in more informal contexts (web forums, questions/answer sites)

Answer (score 0):

I've almost always seen **stylized** to refer to use of a particular style, especially one that aims for a rudimentary effect, at the opposite end of the spectrum from, say, photorealism --  something like the icons for restrooms or "children at play" street signs.

And I usually see the verb **style** and the past-participle **styled** with CSS. So the latter seems the better choice.

Answer (score -3):

A's text is correct since "stylized" is properly spelled and the styling of the page is accomplished "with" CSS.

B's text misspells stylized as "stylised" which is incorrect.

C's text is technically incorrect as CSS does not style anything.  The page designer does the styling using or "with" CSS and possibly some other methods.

While this usage is incorrect, most listeners would likely discern its meaning correctly.

Comment: Thank you.
However, once the page designer is done, each load of the page "is styled by" the CSS.
The action was done once by the designer.
The action is always done by CSS.
"The roof is accessible by the elevator" not "The roof is accessibilized by the elevator" (if "accessibilized" was a word") = my point: The architect is no longer a part of the building, it's elevator, and the roof.  The architect didn't even build the building...

Comment: I disagree with that.  If style is to web page as design is to building, then a building will always have been designed by that architect.  Same with a web page.  The styling was done by a designer with CSS.

Comment: Perhaps my architect/building/etc. example wasn't comparable.
However: "The page is rendered with styling being done by CSS"...
At least we agree on NOT "stylised with"...
If the person attempting to correct the sentence where this all started would have corrected "color" to "colour", then that would be Brittish-English where "stylised" is correct, as I'm being told here in comments/answers.

Comment: @iAmOren I understand your point and you are misapplying a preposition.  Styling is achieved/applied/done **via** CSS during page render,  not **by** CSS.  The styling was done **by** your designer at some point   in the past.  In this case **via** means *by way of*.  Understanding the subtle difference between **via** and **by** is important for just such situations.

Comment: It was complicated enough with "with" and "by" - now I have to add "via" to the mix?!? :)
And if "In this case via means by way of", then "styled by [way of] CSS".  Right?

Comment: Yes and **by** can be and often is substituted for *by way of*.   Feel free to substitute **by** at your own discretion, just be sure to know what it means in such situations.  I think your original usage is fine by the way.  Most people will understand it to mean *by way [use] of*, as jwh20 suggests.

Comment: @EllieK, "I think your original usage is fine by the way": Thank you!
But, which one do you mean?!?  I lost track... :)

Comment: "B's text misspells stylized as "stylised" which is incorrect." - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stylized) lists *stylised* as the usual BrE usage. (Also I do like *styled* more in this context - it avoids confusion with the other meaning of *stylized*, ie. "depicted in an unnatural manner").